# List only Orders containing specific Products

Tags: relations, plugin-craftcommerce

Each Product has a `Merchant` field which is standard Craft `User`. What I'd like to do is list out all Orders which contain one or more Products relating to the `currentUser`. I was hoping I'd be able to use [Relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) to accomplish this, so something like this:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
  'relatedTo': currentUser
}) %}

{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.relatedTo({
  'sourceElement': products,
  'field': 'lineItems.purchasable.product'
}).find %}
```

The first query works fine and returns only the `Products` relating to the `currentUser`, but when I try to use it as the basis for the second query, that's where it collapses in a big heap! Am I in the right ballpark, or isn't this possible in the way I'm trying?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Are you trying to list all Orders where *every* Product is from the merchant or Orders which contain *one or more* Products of the merchant?

Comment: Orders which contain one or more Products of the merchant

Comment: I'm getting no joy with this either. Almost as if the products on an order aren't set up like normal related elements.

Comment: Luke - I asked about this on Slack and there isn't a way to do what I'm asking, but some else has already suggested it on the Craft Feedback site. If you look at my new answer, there is a link where you can go and vote it up if you'd find it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible as of Craft Commerce 1.1.1211 using the new `hasPurchasables` criteria attribute:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-orders#haspurchasables

Comment: Great stuff, I'll be able to make use of this right away.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what I'm trying to do isn't possible (yet).

There is a suggestion for a solution (not created by me) already on the Craft Feedback site. So if you think this would be a useful thing to be able to do, get over there and vote it up, I know I have!

http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/295386-commerce/suggestions/11458980-fetch-orders-based-on-a-product-and-or-product-var