# Get all orders which contains a certain product type

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

In want to print a list of orders:

```
{% set orders = craft.orders.completed(true).limit(null).all() %}
```

Now I want to make a list of orders with only the **product.type** `XYZ`.

I tried to fabricate something out of this [question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15284/list-only-orders-containing-specific-products). But I'd like specific product types:

```
{% set orders = craft.orders.completed(true).hasPurchasables([type.XYZ]).limit(null).all() %}
```

This returns:

> Variable "type" does not exist.

How do I have to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Products themselves aren't [Purchasebles](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v3/products.html#purchasables).

However, [Variants](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v3/products.html#variants) of products are. And you can have more than one Variant of a Product.

So, we need to get all Variants of a particular Product type and then feed your query:

```
{# get products of a certain type #}
{% set productIds = craft.products.type('classes').ids() %}

{# get the variants from those product Ids #}
{% set theVariants = craft.variants.productId(productIds).all() %}

{# grab orders #}
{% set orders = craft.orders.completed(true).hasPurchasables(theVariants).limit(null).all() %}
```

You'll probably want to `limit` the orders returned at some point depending on how you're displaying or querying them.

Comment: It works. But I just noticed that if a customer has two items of `product.type` ordered. Then the order is shown twice.

Comment: I tried to query the thing with `.unique()`. No luck so far